# Is this a correct O((logn)^2) algorithm to find local minima of a 2-d array?

Tags: algorithm

I tried solving a problem to find the local minima of a n*n 2D array . All elements of the 2D array are distinct. Till now I have done this

Definition of a local minimum of a 2D array:

A[i][j] is a local minimum if:

- A[i][j] < A [i+1] [j]
- A[i][j] < A [i-1] [j]
- A[i][j] < A [i] [j+1]
- A[i][j] < A [i] [j-1]

**MinColumn Function:** *This function receives three inputs from its preceding function: the 2D array M, the index of middle column or essentially the column to consider, and the total number of columns in current recursion*

I used divide and conquer to find the minimum element of that column and return it back to caller. Time complexity of this algorithm is *O(log n)*, because the `while` loop reduces the items to be considered by a factor of 2. *hence it's time complexity is *O(log n)*

```
MinColumn(M[][],int mid,int last){
    L<-0,R <-last;
    found <- False;
    while(found == false){
        mid2 <- (L+R)/2 
        if(M[mid2][mid] is local minimum of column){
            found <- True
            return mid2
        }
        else if( M[mid2-1][mid] < M[mid2][mid])
            R <- mid2-1
        else 
            L <- mid2 +1
    }
    return mid2;
}
```

**MinGrid Function** *this function first is to find out local minima of the 2D array. I find the local minima of 2D array by divide and conquer method*

It first finds the middle column of the 2D array, calls the *MinColumn* function to find the minimum element of middle column, then I check if this minimum element is a local minimum or not. If not then I check which column of *mid+1* or *mid-1*  has a smaller value than the value considered

If left value is smaller, then our local minimum is on the left side, if right value is smaller then the local minimum is on the right side. Then I change L/R according to the situation and ultimately end up on a local minimum.

```
MinGrid(M[][]){    
    L<-0,R <-last;
    found <- False;
    while(found == false){
        mid <- (L+R)/2
        i <- Mincolumn(M,mid,R);
        if(M[i][mid] is local minima)
            return M[i][mid]    
        else  if(M[mid2][mid+1] < M[i][mid])
            L <- mid+1
        else R <- mid-1
    }
}
```

Now the *O()* complexity of *Mincolumn* is *O(logn)* and the function *MinGrid* is operated by a `while` loop which iterated at most *log(n)* times. So while finding the complexity of *MinGrid* I will write

```
MinGrid(M[][]){    
    L<-0,R <-last; b    // O(1)
    found <- False;
    while(found == false){     // iterates over log n times
        mid <- (L+R)/2             // O(1)
        i <- Mincolumn(M,mid,R);   // O(log n)
        if(M[i][mid] is local minimum)
            return M[i][mid]         
        else  if(M[mid2][mid+1] < M[i][mid])  //O(1)
            L <- mid+1    //O(1)
        else R <- mid-1
    }
}
```

Hence in total O(f(n)) = log(n)*(log(n) + c*O(1))

Hence O(f(n)) = (log(n))^2;

Specifically my doubt is on the **MinGrid** part , I think that its complexity is *(log(n))^2*, since the called function is of *O(log n)* complexity and the other components in while loop are *O(1)*, making my **MinGrid** an *O((log(n))^2)* algorithm .

Comment: We are not a debugging/code audit service. Read [ask]. And learn how to format your code, this is just unreadable.

Comment: Edited it . Hope it follows the rules .

Comment: BTW, this is tag as C but it is basically a pseudo-code.

Comment: No, your algorithm is not correct. MinColumn doesn't find all of local minima in a given column, it cannot do that with this complexity, it only finds one (if at all). A grid local minimum may exist and correspond to a column local minimum MinColumn misses.

Comment: The algorithm is indeed not correct. For instance the value of *R* is used for row and column index at the same time (it is passed as *last* to *MinColumn* where it is a row index, and it is used in *MinGrid* as column index). Even if that were corrected by passing *last* instead of *R* as last argument to *MinColumn*, you could construct a matrix of 9x9 where the algorithm would not find a local minimum, and would end up in an infinite loop.

Comment: Okay , my bad, I forgot to mention I just want to find a single local minima in a given 2-d array .

Comment: FYI "minima" is a plural of "minimum", so no such thing as "single minima". Whatever it's called your algorithm doesn't find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately your algorithm is not correct. The problem is in the part:

> If left value is smaller, then our local minimum is on the left side,
>   if right value is smaller then the local minimum is on the right side.
>   Then I change L/R according to the situation and ultimately end up on
>   a local minimum.

Consider this case - the only local minimum is 11

```
19 29 39
18 28 38
17 27 37
16 20 36
15 26 35
14 25 34
13 12 11
```

First the algorithm finds local minimum of the middle column: 20. Then it chooses to go left, where it finds 13 and outputs that as the result. It does not even consider the third column (which holds the only correct solution).

Comment: "You can get working O(nlog(n)) algorithm by trying to find all the local minima in certain column, and only if there are none recursing on the left/right side." That's rather unlikely.

Comment: @n.m. Thanks for pointing that out, it surely is not that simple. How about searching the whole column, if there's no local minimum taking the smallest number in column and recursing in the direction of the smaller neighboring value? W.l.o.g. let that be the left side. Than all the numbers on the right boundary are larger, so there's at least one local minimum on the left side etc. etc.

Comment: Oh well, you are right once again :), it won't work..There's no guarantee that the numbers on the boundary will all be larger than the numbers on the left side. Just wondering, is there any NlogN algorithm?